# Sentence structure: Can I not try that?

Tags: grammar

Does the sentence "Can I not try that?" mean:

1. I want to try that but I'm not allowed to
2. I don't want to try that

Comment: It's ambiguous. But neither of your interpretations are likely. I would say it more probably means one of two things: (1) *Am I allowed to try that?* (2) *Am I capable of trying that?* Or, in its negative phrasing, *Are you saying I'm not (allowed / able) to try that?*

Comment: I automatically read it with an emphasis on "not," and so I interpret it as a sarcastic way to say, "I don't want to try that." Ex. Person 1: "Look, they're bungee-jumping." Person 2: "Can I try that?" Person 3: "Uh, can I *not* try that?"

Answer (score 1):

"Can I try that?" would be a simple question. "Am I allowed to try to do something?" Modifying try with "not" implies a slight fear that permitting the action might violate a formal or informal rule, or that the requester might lack the ability to successfully perform the action.